# Extracting tuple elements from a string

Tags: bash

Suppose that I have a string in the following format:

```
(x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) (x3,y3,z3)
```

-99 <= `xi`,`yi`,`zi` <= 99

What is the easiest way to get `x1` and `y1`?

I tried the following which works but I think my approach is not elegant enough.

```
string="(x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) (x3,y3,z3)"
x1=( $(echo $string | cut -d"," -f1 | cut -d"(" -f2) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '(x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) (x3,y3,z3)' | awk -F'[(,]' '{print $2, $3}'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for awk or any other tool, bash can handle it:

```
string='(x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) (x3,y3,z3)'

IFS=',(' read _ x1 y1 _ <<< "$string"
echo "$x1" # prints x1
echo "$y1" # prints y1
```